# multithreading in Julia

Tags: parallel-processing, julia, jupyter-notebook

If I want to set the number of thread and run it on terminal, I use

```
export JULIA_NUM_THREADS=4
```

but what do I have to do, If I want to parallelise my program on Jupiter notebook? How can I set the number of threads that I want?

Comment: you can do that and then run Jupyter from that same terminal.

Comment: I can't understand can you explain it more? I want to write a report on notebook and I can't do this on it

Comment: Can't we write it by Jupyter? I want to give report to someone, so I want them run the notebook file and they don't want to write anything in terminal.

Comment: Do you need to use threads or can you use procs/tasks?

Comment: To elaborate on @AlexanderMorley's question, will it suffice to write `addprocs(4)` at the top of your notebook code?

Comment: @ChrisRackauckas is right. I could do that. but I was wondering If I could set the number of threads in Jupyter notebook without setting them in terminal.